# jQuery: using "stopPropagation" for Collapsible Menu prevents AJAX content loading into DIV

Tags: jquery, ajax, menu, nav

I used to load a html-file using load() into a DIV, which just worked fine. I also implemented a html5 history "back-button" functionality which works with ajax.

But now I try to use this neat code for implementing a collapsible vertical navigation menu. I like the code because my requirements for the menu are not too much, and because it does (almost) exactly what I want:

[Jquery Navmenu Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chufol/nQNnP/)

```
    //auto-close siblings
    $('nav li').click(function(e) {
        $(this).find('>ul').stop(true, true).slideToggle(10, "linear")
            .end().siblings().find('ul').slideUp(10, "linear");
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Problem is, the navigation menu requires `e.stopPropagation()`, for the submenus expanding & closing as intended.
But as long as e.stopPropagation() is in the code, for sure my ajax code won't load the stuff into the div when I click a hyperlink in the new navigation menu - it will load as new page (as if I didn't use preventDefault()).

So, my QUESTION:
Are there some simple lines of code to add to the nav menu, to get the same menu behaviour, but still "bubbling up the DOM tree"?

Another small issue:
Unlike in the example code on jsfiddle, my nav menu always is totally expanded when I'm initially loading the index.html. I don't understand that.. Code is the same, at least for the nav menu..

thanks so much!   j

here's the whole script stuff 
(my menu is just using an unordered list in a `<nav>`, with all linking anchors having rel="tab" for the AJAX Div loading):

```
<script>
$(function () {
    <!-- AJAX: load html-pages dynamically into this site's div (#content-main), and add browser history and URL support -->
    //To override the default action for the link(anchor tag), use the following jQuery code snippet.
    $('body').on('click', "a[rel='tab']", function (e) {
        //code for the link action
        return false;
    });


    //Now to get the ajax content and display it and change the browser URL to the specific location without refresh use the following code.
    //$("a[rel='tab']").click(function(e) {
    $('body').on('click', "a[rel='tab']", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        /*
        if uncomment the ABOVE line, html5 nonsupported browers won't change the url but will display the ajax content;
        if commented, html5 nonsupported browers will reload the page to the specified link.
        */

        //"destroy function does not revert slider to original state, it just cleans up all events and data related to slider, so you can remove it safely without memory leaks."
        if( $('.royalSlider').length ) $('.royalSlider').royalSlider('destroy');

        //get the link location that was clicked
        pageurl = $(this).attr('href');

        //to get the ajax content and display in div #content-main
        $('#content-main').load(pageurl+'?rel=tab'+'#content-main');

        //to change the browser URL to the given link location
        if(pageurl!=window.location){
            window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl);
        }
        //stop refreshing to the page given in
        return false;
    });

    //the below code is to override back button to get the ajax content without page reload
    //added some details from http://rosspenman.com/pushstate-jquery/
    $(window).on('popstate', function(e) {
        if (e.originalEvent.state !== null) {
            $('#content-main').load(location.pathname+'?rel=tab'+'#content-main');
        }
        else {
            $('body').load(location.pathname+'?rel=tab'+'#content-main');
        }
    });



    <!-- Collapsible Menu -->
    //auto-close siblings
    $('nav li').click(function(e) {
        $(this).find('>ul').stop(true, true).slideToggle(10, "linear")
            .end().siblings().find('ul').slideUp(10, "linear");
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: You mean $('nav li').click(function(e) doesn't work for the new elements yes?

Comment: no, it still works, independent of the existence of e.stopPropagation() - The functionality of expanding/closing the menu still works fine. But if e.stopPropagation() exists, all hyperlinks in the <nav> will open the links in a new page.  And if I get rid of e.stopPropagation(), the ajax works fine, but the menu navigation will not expand/close correctly, see [jsfiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/nQNnP/2/)